# In Visual Studio Code, can I change multiple keyboard shortcuts at once?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to change all default keyboard shortcuts starting with 'Ctrl + K' to something else (say 'Alt + K'). Is there any way in Visual Studio Code to do that at once?

I know that it can be done by selecting one Keyboard shortcut at a time, but is there a way to do this all at once, something similar to Find/Replace of keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help:

- <kbd>f1</kbd> -> open keyboard shortcuts.
- Press brackets button on top right.
- Cut all of your preferences and save them in another file without the first and last square brackets.
- First step again.
- Search for `ctrl k`.
- Select the first one - press and hold <kbd>delete</kbd> -> Delete all of them (This is easy!).
- On the top right click on the brackets button. (Open keyboard shortcuts(json)).
- Deleted shortcuts have been added to this file with a `-` behind them on the command value. Each have an opening bracket, key value, command value, and closing bracket.
- Select one of the opening brackts, then press and hold <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>.
- Double press down arrow, then <kbd>home</kbd> button.
- Delete the first `-` from all of the command values with this trick.
- Then go to the key values and change them all to what you want. Please note that some of them may be in `ctrl+k+...` form, but some others in `ctrl+alt+k+...` or `ctrl+shift+k+...` form. You can't change them with this trick!

Comment: This trick actually works, however you have to be extremely careful and know exactly what you are doing. That said, it would be nice if there was a nicer way to edit this, instead of hacking yourself through keyboard shortcuts... At least this is the best solution that I could find on the internet. There were no other solutions to this specific issue.

Comment: (There were also changes needed. Like DEL does not work. You have to keep typing DEL for it to delete existing shortcuts. You also have to click on a different symbol, as there is no brackets symbol.)

Comment: Additionally, you cannot only delete the minuses. You need to duplicate all entries, and then keep one entry with the minus and the other should be modified. Else default keys are inserted and your modified keys in `keybindings.json` are ignored.

Comment: Unfortunately, the {} has disappeared from the interface as has "Export Key Bindings" so this has gotten much harder since you have to (somehow) merge the default key bindings with your overrides in User/keybindings.json, then put everything you want to modify in "User/keybindings.json", since it's being overridden from the immutable defaults, then mess with it.